# Solidity assembly: `target_slot`. Is it an opcode or other stuff?

Tags: solidity, assembly, slots

I found this [strange variable](https://etherscan.io/address/0x57ab1ec28d129707052df4df418d58a2d46d5f51#code) or opcode in inline assembly, but I'm not sure: `target_ slot`. I couldn't find its definition in the contract. I prefer it to be an opcode, but I didn't seem to find it when I looked up the documentation. The following is the code snippet:

```
function()
    external
    payable
{
    if (useDELEGATECALL) {
        assembly {
            /* Copy call data into free memory region. */
            let free_ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(free_ptr, 0, calldatasize)

            /* Forward all gas and call data to the target contract. */
            let result := delegatecall(gas, sload(target_slot), free_ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
            returndatacopy(free_ptr, 0, returndatasize)

            /* Revert if the call failed, otherwise return the result. */
            if iszero(result) { revert(free_ptr, returndatasize) }
            return(free_ptr, returndatasize)
        }
    } else {
```

What did I miss? Is it the slot of `target` variable? If it is true, it is strange. I can use hello_slot to get the slot of `hello` variable, use world_slot to get the slot of `world` variable and so on?

Because he is in `pragma solidity 0.4.25`, I think it has a writing style similar to `xxxx.slot`, which obtains the slot of the xxxx variable. Is that what it looks like?